# In Pandas module of python pandas.read_excel is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel?

Error: Object `pd.read_excel` not found.
```

My xlrd package is updated. I couldn't find any solution to it. Please help!! I m doing it in ipython-notebook.

Comment: can you tell us ```pd.version.version```?

Comment: Update your version of pandas

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably using an old version of `pandas` . Try using - [`pandas.io.excel.read_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html) (or in your case `pd.io.excel.read_excel` )